# Click events inside UIWebView with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

I've built a simple app/service that I'm displaying inside a UIWebView. Traditional links work just fine, but click events don't work at all. I'm aware this is a "thing" and I've looked at lots of code samples, and looked into `touchstart` etc., but nothing seems to make a dent in the problem.

Is there a definitive guide to making JS click events work inside web views, even if it involves passing messages to iOS?

Underlying app is Rails/Coffeescript. Current event code looks like this:

`$('#frame ul li').on "click", ->
   # Do stuff`

Answer (score 0):

Don't you use hosting jQuery on the Google server?  The resource is likely to blocked by App Transport Security (ATS).

If so, the easy way is to set the domain to `NSExceptionDomains`.